# Python copying rows with same ID values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe with columns including ID and multiple values and different rows can have same or different ID values. I would like to create a new dataframe so, that every row has only one ID and the specific column values are just appended next to the ID. The Dataframe also has other columns with additional values that are same for same ID rows that i would like to keep

| ID | type1 | type2 | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dog | yellow | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | dog | yellow | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 2 | cat | brown | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | mouse | blue | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | dog | yellow | 1 | 2 | 3 |

expected output:

| ID | type1 | type2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dog | yellow | 1 2 3 5 6 7 1 2 3 |
| 2 | cat | brown | 1 1 1 |
| 3 | mouse | blue | 1 1 1 |

I have been exploring the groupby option, can't get it to have this kind of output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
group = ['ID', 'type1', 'type2']
out = df.melt(group).groupby(group, as_index=False)['value'].agg(list)
```

Output:

```
   ID  type1   type2                        value
0   1    dog  yellow  [1, 5, 1, 2, 6, 2, 3, 7, 3]
1   2    cat   brown                    [1, 1, 1]
2   3  mouse    blue                    [1, 1, 1]
```

If order matters:

```
out = (df.set_index(group).stack().groupby(group).agg(list)
         .reset_index(name='value')
       )
```

Output:

```
   ID  type1   type2                        value
0   1    dog  yellow  [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3]
1   2    cat   brown                    [1, 1, 1]
2   3  mouse    blue                    [1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'animal': ['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'fish'],
    'color': ['yellow', 'yellow', 'brown', 'blue', 'yellow', 'brown', 'blue', 'red'],
    'value1': [1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5],
    'value2': [2, 6, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3],
    'value3': [3, 7, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4]
})
"""print(df.to_string())
  ID  type1   type2  value1  value2  value3
0   1    dog  yellow       1       2       3
1   1    dog  yellow       5       6       7
2   2    cat   brown       1       1       1
3   3  mouse    blue       1       1       1
4   1    dog  yellow       1       2       3
5   2    cat   brown       1       1       1
6   3  mouse    blue       1       1       1
7   4   fish     red       5       3       4"""
# Automatically identify group and value columns, considering first 3 and last 3
group_cols = list(df)[:3] # First 3 columns
"""print(group_cols)
['ID', 'animal', 'color']"""
value_cols = list(df)[-3:] # last 3 columns
"""print(value_cols)
['value1', 'value2', 'value3']"""

res =( df.melt(id_vars = group_cols,var_name='value_type',value_name='value')
.groupby(group_cols)['value'].agg(list)
.reset_index(name='value')
.sort_values(by=group_cols)
)
print(res)
"""   ID animal   color                        value
0   1    dog  yellow  [1, 5, 1, 2, 6, 2, 3, 7, 3]
1   2    cat   brown           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
2   3  mouse    blue           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
3   4   fish     red                    [5, 3, 4]
"""
```